# How do I make a span12 100% in bootstrap. Im trying to make everything 100% of the screen size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, width, screen, html

Ok so im trying to make a span with content in it go across the screen 100% and for some reason everytime I do width:100% on the span it shows up weird,it extended off to the right all the way and leaves a margin on the left side of it. im not even sure if I should use span for this but I would guess so. im trying to make my span12 take up 100% of the screen.

my code looks basic:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
    <ul class="inline"> 

      <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

the span12 as you know does not take up 100% entirely it leaves about a 20px or so margin on both sides.

**UPDATE:**

Ok if you do this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Untitled</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

<style type="text/css">

.span12 {
background:#999;
padding:20px 0px;
}
/*THIS IS A GREY BOX THAT GOES ACROSS THE ENTIRE SCREEN end*/

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">

   <div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span12">
  <p>THIS IS THE GREY BOX CONTENT THAT I WANT GOING ACROSS THE ENTIRE SCREEN 1OO% WITH NO MARGIN THATS THE SPAN12 HAS ON THE SIDES</p>

   </div><!--span12 END-->
   </div><!--row END-->
   </div><!--container END-->

</body>
```

**you will have a grey box going across the screen and as you know span12 fluid does not go ALL the way across the screen it has about a 20px or so margin on the left and right of the span. I want the span12 (grey box) to have the width of 100% going across the entire screen.**

I have tryed html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; } and it does not work the span12 still has margins on the side of instead of going 100% (entire screen)

Comment: Do you have any example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Could you explain what is your problem with an image or something? I can't see nothing strange with that layout: http://bootply.com/61158

Comment: My reputation is to low read my questions again it got updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the container fluid to fit the window size, just remove the padding from `.container-fluid` with:

```
.container-fluid {
  padding: 0;
}
```

And also remove the padding from the body for mobile layouts:

```
body {
  padding: 0;
}
```

You can see the working example here: http://bootply.com/61164

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following CSS:

```
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Comment: My reputation is to low read my questions again it got updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove margins with css. To remove the left margins you can do something like:

`body {
    left-margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}`

However, you are getting some margins because of the `<ul>` tags. To remove these you can do:

`ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}`

If you want to put the links all the way to the left you can add to the `<ul>` tag's css :

`list-style-type: none:`

This will move the links all the way to the left without any margin. However, his will remove the bullets too. The bullets (or any other `list-style-type`) has an inherent margin so you will not be able to remove it in its entirety.

Comment: My reputation is to low read my questions again it got updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a .container-full or if your after a background colour then use container-fluid as the gutters are created by padding so the background colour or image will span across full screen.

Answer (score -1):

To achieve 100% across the screen I change the word container to envelope and apply whatever css I want to .envelope. Works for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I read something into the question that I assumed was there. When I build a site (sample code) <div class="container">

<div class="row-fluid">

<div class="span12">
</div>
</div>
</div>

Comment: Continued:       Using the word container limits the page to 1270px in width for a span12 or about 3/4ths of the screen under Bootstrap CSS  By changing the word from container to say envelope then the 1270px restriction is gone. Then you can put what ever styling you want for the envelope div.